# Angular.js with Stripe

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I am using angular.js for Stripe Integration.
I found a couple of libraries for anuglar.js but I think they don't provide features.

This is what I am trying to do on angular.js using Stripe API for subscription payment.

1. Create Customer.
2. Add credit card information on this customer.
3. Add customer with subscription plan.
4. Check customer's subscription is expired or not.
5. If expired, renew subscription.

Does stripe.js will handle this?
What libraries should I use? if not, is it possible using standard $http.post for stripe API?

Looking forward your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A payment flow with Stripe is divided in two parts:

- client-side, in your frontend code, you collect and tokenize the customer's payment information using [Stripe.js](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js) or [Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout). You then send the token to your server
- server-side, in your backend code, you use the token in an API request, e.g. to [create a charge](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge) or [a customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_customer)

Except for token creation requests, all other API requests need to be sent using your secret API key, so you can't do this from your frontend code without revealing the secret API key, which you definitely don't want to do (because then anyone could retrieve it and use it to send API requests on your behalf).